# unity can't record audio with kinect V2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect-v2

I want to record audio in Unity with the microphone from the kinectV2.

I tried:
audio.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 200, 22050)

But that doesn't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEzKL.jpg

The only input I have is a Kinect NUI sensor. Here's the code I use for recording:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RA : MonoBehaviour {

    bool isRecord = true;

    public AudioSource audio;

    void OnGUI(){
        if(isRecord){
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2-50,200,100), "Record")){ // start
                isRecord = !isRecord;
                audio.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, 200, 22050); // 200s 22050 Hz 
            }
        }else{
            // stop, play
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-100, Screen.height/2-50,200,100), "Close & Play")){
                isRecord = !isRecord;
                Microphone.End(null);
                audio.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error code I'm getting:

---

> Starting Microphone failed. result=25 (Unsupported file or audio format. )
>   UnityEngine.Microphone:Start(String, Boolean, Int32, Int32)

Comment: Same exact issue here with the Kinect microphone so doesn't seem like a one-off issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with Unity and lack of support for Microphone Arrays, which is what the Kinect has.

Similar issues on Unity forum:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/capturing-from-a-microphone-array-errors-in-all-unity-versions.849781/